# Does wireless charging work in Cyanogenmod 12?

Tags: cyanogenmod, wireless-charging

I'm curious if anyone has successfully tested wireless charging. I was thinking about getting the back cover for my S5 and a wireless pad, but don't want to invest if it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: The software has no impact on the charging process. It's just electromagnetism. Whether or not the phone is able to realize it's charging is another matter, but it wouldn't affect your ability to actually charge it. I would imagine the notifications would work fine, though, since vanilla Android supports it.

Comment: Software absolutely could have an effect on it. I'm not saying that it does, but for example a switch could be in place that allowed software to activate or deactivate it. I'm just curious if anyone has had any luck with it. Also I've read posts in the past about how a kernal update was slowing down the charging process by limiting the intake rate. Regardless, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Cyanogen 12.1 nightlies on my Nexus 5 and while wireless charging works it does seem slower than with stock or cataclysm. I was using Franco and ElementalX on those ROMs but stock on CM12. Hope that helps!